# Display no of listings on a page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with an RoR project where I've implemented a search page which is working fine, what I'm looking to achieve is [the number of listings](http://screencast.com/t/Rp7Ytncbut).

Actually, what I've used here is hardcoded HTML since I don't know what code or gem to use. Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code snippet might help you:

```
<div class="digg_pagination">
    <div clas="page_info">
      <%= page_entries_info @posts %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @posts, :container => false %>
  </div>
```

See [this link](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/will_paginate/) for more details.

Comment: Viola, it worked using your code, specifically I only required <%= page_entries_info @posts %> thanks, you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination through GEM kaminari(replacement of will_paginate). Just see [this Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a gem called 'will_paginate'.
[Here's its homepage on Github](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Comment: Hi, I'm using this gem to display the pagination, but is it possible to display the no of listings also?